# What kind of weight does default UPS and USPS take in consideration?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, ups, usps, multishipping

I'm using Magento Community 1.9.2, I'm new at this and I want to set shipping properly with UPS and USPS.
I've set weight along with length, width and height (these 3 are custom attributes) for each of my products and I can see that at shipping options only weight is taken in consideration for UPS and USPS.

I have products that fit in an envelope and products that fit in a box, so I can't charge standard flat rate.

My question is: what the measurement unit of UPS and USPS and what's the best way to setup this properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, Magento only sends weight information to UPS and USPS.

- The measurement unit for USPS is imperial: pounds
- The measurement unit for UPS is editable in `System Configuration > Shipping Methods > UPS > Weight Unit`: LBS or KGS

As it sounds like you are needing better data sent, I suggest looking into WebShopApps Dimensional Shipping module: http://webshopapps.com/us/shipping/dimensional-shipping.html. The packaging aspect can get pretty tricky, so it is nice to use a pre-built module to take care of that.

Comment: My store in India, so my default weight KGS. UPS for USA shipping, what i need to do with "Weight Unit"   KGS or LBS?